# Mimic Javascript escape() function

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, encoding, escaping

As shown in this table http://www.javascripter.net/faq/accentedcharacters.htm, there's a difference between `escape()` and `encodeURI()`.

I need to mimic the behavior of `escape()`, as it's needed by another system, but turns out is complicated with Python.

```
msg = "¿El mañana exitirá?"

# javascript: console.log(escape(msg)) # %BFEl%20ma%F1ana%20exitir%E1%3F
q = urllib.parse.quote(msg)
print(q) # %C2%BFEl%20ma%C3%B1ana%20exitir%C3%A1%3F

q = urllib.parse.quote(msg, encoding="unicode_escape")
print(q) # %5CxbfEl%20ma%5Cxf1ana%20exitir%5Cxe1%3F
```

How can I make Python mimic `escape`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I was pretty close:

```
msg = "¿El mañana exitirá?"
q = urllib.parse.quote(msg, encoding="raw_unicode_escape")
print(q) # %BFEl%20ma%F1ana%20exitir%E1%3F
```